# Ubuntu NVIDIA Driver Change now Won't Boot into Unity

Tags: ubuntu, video-card

I was having problems with OpenGL support on my video card on UBuntu, so I went into Software & Updates, additional drivers, and changed the driver. There were 3 drivers listed, and the one i was on was XOrg, which I understand is some kind of default driver. I switched to a proprietary NVIDEA driver that was available and rebooted, now it won't load my desktop and goes straight into a tty console, which is flashing so I assume the driver is NOT WORKING. I have trouble even typing in my login info in the tty, I guess i need to go back to the old driver?

Finding information on how to switch between available drivers using the terminal only is surprisingly really frustrating you'd think this would be @#$^#$^ simple enough but it aint.

If i type

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

It shows my NVIDIA Corporation GT218 video card and 3 available drivers:

```
nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
nvidia-304 - distro non-free
```

If i type

```
sudo lshw -c display
```

It shows my 2 video cards (the second one, ATI, has never worked since I installed Ubuntu and I don't plug anything into it). The NVIDIA one shows:

```
...
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
...
```

How do i switch back to the goddamn xserver-xorg-video-nouveau driver????? First and foremost I need access to the desktop and I can't deal with this tty only. If i uninstall the other 2 drivers, would that force it to use the nouveau driver and everything would go back to normal? And this is a problem because I don't think the nouveau driver supports OpenGL 4.0, which I need and is the whole reason i started this dang headache. Would finding the latest greatest NVIDIA driver for my GT218 solve this problem, or is that the proprietary driver that Ubuntu is listing.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you go back to the open source driver (which is fine for kicad etc) you can get a real problem with this. The Nvidia can black list the old driver and when uninstalled leaves the blacklist file in place leaving you with a low res screen. The way to fix it is to go to /etc/modprobe.d and look for a file named something like nvidia_graphics_drivers....conf. Either delete this or rename it to something without .conf at the end. reboot. enjoy your open source driver.